# Delphi customised constructor in TComponent never runs

Tags: delphi

i am new to delphi and i am creating a component in delphi 6. but i can't get the constructor to run:

```
unit MyComms1;
...
type
  TMyComms = class(TComponent)
    public
      constructor MyConstructor;
    end;
implementation

constructor TMyComms.MyConstructor;
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('got here');
end;
```

it doesn't matter what the constructor is called, but this code doesn't run the constructor at all.

**edit**

by request, here is how the `TMyComms` class is initialized (this code is in a different file called TestComms.pas):

```
unit TestComms;

interface

uses MyComms1, ...

type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MyCommsHandle = TMyComms;
    ...
    procedure BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

procedure TForm1.BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyCommsHandle.AnotherMyCommsProcedure;
end;
```

**edit 2**

reading some of the answers it looks like constructors must be manually called in delphi. is this correct? if so then this is certainly my main error - i am used to php where the `__construct` function is automatically called whenever a class is assigned to a handle.

Comment: You can have as many constructors as you like so I don't know if and how PHP resolves that but afaik, `Java`, `C#`, `C++`, ..., `Delphi` **all** require the right constructor to be called manually.

Comment: The big issue here is virtual constructors. @mull are you interested in learning about that issue.

Comment: You'll have to change *many* habits you acquired in PHP. I guess, that it will be wise *not to* assume, that language constructs work similarly to PHP, because usually they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not follow the Delphi naming guidelines - the constructor should be named `Create`.

Since you didn't posted the code actually calling the ctor, I guess, that you may not have called it at all. Try to add a button to your form, doubleclick it and add the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender : TObject)

var comms : TMyComms;

begin
  comms := TMyComms.MyConstructor;
  comms.Free;
end;
```

By the way, if you derive from TComponent, you should override constructor with a parameter - otherwise inherited methods may not work properly.

```
interface

type TMyComms = class(TComponent)
  private
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyComms.Create(AOwner : TComponent)
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // Your stuff
end;

// Somewhere in code
var comms : TMyComms;

begin
comms := TMyComms.Create(nil);
end;
```

Comment: cheers. are you saying that i can rename `MyConstructor` to `Create` as per your second code snippet and ignore the first code snippet? if so then unfortunately my constructor still does not run.

Comment: The ctor *may* be named MyConstructor, however general Delphi naming guidelines say, that ctors *should* be named Create. That does not matter in the case of being or not being called. You did not tell us, though, *how* are you trying to invoke the ctor (it should be invoked during class creation), so I cannot help you further until you post some code (please edit your question in such case).

Comment: ah thanks for the clarification. i will post the code for how i initialize the `TMyComms` class

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are not calling `TMyComms.MyConstructor` to test your unusual called and used constructor. The way marked with `// **` would be th most usual.

```
type
  TMyComms = class(TComponent)
    public
      constructor MyConstructor;
     // the usual override;
     // constructor Create(Owner:TComponent);override; // **    
      constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);overload; override;
      constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent;AnOtherParameter:Integer);overload;    
    end;

constructor TMyComms.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited ;
  ShowMessage('got here Create');
end;

constructor TMyComms.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AnOtherParameter: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ShowMessage(Format('got here Create with new parametere %d',[AnOtherParameter]));
end;

constructor TMyComms.MyConstructor;
begin
  inherited Create(nil);
  ShowMessage('got here MyConstructor');
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TMyComms.MyConstructor.Free;
    TMyComms.Create(self).Free;
    TMyComms.Create(self,1234).Free;

end;
```

Comment: The `Create(AOwner: TComponent)` constructor needs to be declared as an `override`. You can also `overload` it.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom constructor is not called because you did not call it.

```
MyComm := TMyComms.MyConstructor;
```

But you also have an error in your code. Because there is no derived constructor you can inherite with simple `inherited`.

```
type
  TMyComms = class(TComponent)
    public
      constructor MyConstructor;
    end;
implementation

constructor TMyComms.MyConstructor;
begin
  inherited Create( nil ); // !
  ShowMessage('got here');
end;
```

You can use the simple `inherited` if your custom constructor use the same name and parameters from an existing constructor.

```
type
  TMyComms = class(TComponent)
    public
      constructor Create( AOwner : TComponent ); override;
    end;
implementation

constructor TMyComms.Create( AOwner : TComponent );
begin
  inherited; // <- everything is fine
  ShowMessage('got here');
end;
```

Comment: it was my understanding that a constructor is automatically called when the class is assigned to a handle. are you saying that i have to specifically call the constructor procedure?

Comment: Yes, in Delphi you have to create an instance by calling the constructor like `LInstanceVar := TMyClass.Create;`.

Comment: And if you want the component to be DFM-streamable, then you MUST override the virtual `TComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent)` constructor, since that is the constructor that the DFM streaming system calls.